# Design pattern for transforming the fields of a Java Object

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Message {

  private String sender;

  private Set<String> receivers;

  private String text;

}
```

The `Message` class can be extended by `EmailMessage` and `SMSMessage` having their own additional fields.

There are 2 services - EmailService and SMSService.
They both do the following operations:

1. Take the message object which contains sender and receiver user ids.
2. EmailService calls another service to transform the user ids to email ids. SMSService does the same to  transform the user ids to phone numbers.
3. The Message object should be transformed to EmailMessage and SMSMEssage in their respective services.
4. Send the EmailMessage and SMSMessage.

I've been going through many design patterns to solve this problem. But I didn't find any such pattern to transform the fields of an object and/or convert the parent object to a child object.
The only design patterns that come close are Strategy and Decorator.
I'm using Strategy Pattern for using either EmailService or SMSService at runtime. It is solving just one part of my problem. Will Decorator Pattern help for solving the other?

**Edit:** Adding the current implementation

```
public abstract class AbstractMessageService<T extends Message> {

  @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)  
  public final void consume(Message message) {  
    T convertedMessage = getMessageConverterStrategy().convert(message);
    send(convertedNotificationMessage);
  }

  protected abstract void send(T message) throws Exception;

  protected abstract MessageConverterStrategy getMessageConverterStrategy();  

}
```

```
@KafkaListener(
    topics = "topicName",
    groupId = "email-group")
public class EmailService extends AbstractMessageService<EmailMessage> {

  @Override
  protected void send(EmailMessage message) {
    // Some logic to send email.
  }

  @Override
  protected MessageConverterStrategy getMessageConverterStrategy() {
    return new EmailMessageConverterStrategy();
  }  

}
```

```
@KafkaListener(
    topics = "topicName",
    groupId = "sms-group")
public class SMSService extends AbstractMessageService<SMSMessage> {

  @Override
  protected void send(SMSMessage message) {
    // Some logic to send sms.
  }

  @Override
  protected MessageConverterStrategy getMessageConverterStrategy() {
    return new SMSMessageConverterStrategy();
  }  

}
```

```
public interface MessageConverterStrategy<T extends Message> {

  T convert(Message message);

}
```

In the SMSMessageConverterStrategy and EmailMessageConverterStrategy, I want to use other design pattern to do the conversion of Message to SMSMessage and EmailMessage respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to convert almost everything, I think `Message` and `Email` and `SMS` are not related. I think you should use Factory method like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Message m = new Message();
        Email email = Email.from(m);
        EmailService.sendMail(email);
    }
}

class Message {
      private String sender;
      private Set<String> receivers;
      private String text;
}

class Email {
    private String senderMailId;
    private String text;
    private Set<String> receiverMailIds;

    //make it private
    private Email() {

    }
    
    public static Email from(Message m) {
        Email email = new Email();
        email.senderMailId = ""; //call MappingService.toEmailId(m.getSender());
        //do rest of the conversion and processing
        return email;
    }
}

class EmailService {
    public static void sendMail(Email e) {
        //send the mail
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the implementation I have done so far. In my EmailMessageConverterStrategy and SmsMessageConverterStrategy, I'm doing something similar. I'm using some service to convert and then using setters to set the values. The reason I'm asking for having a design pattern to do this is to ensure that the ids are converted for each Service that I'll add in the future.

Comment: FYI, `Email.from()` is a [Static Factory Method](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info), not to be confused with the GoF Factory Method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of **Factory method** pattern.

A `MessageService` which would be implemented by `SmsService` and `EmailService`.

```java
interface MessageService {
    Message transform(Message message);

}

class SmsService implements MessageService {
    @Override
    SmsMessage transform(Message message) {
        // do appropriate transformation and return.
    }
}

class EmailService implements MessageService {
    @Override
    EmailMessage transform(Message message) {
        // do appropriate transformation and return.
    }
}
```

Then use a factory to create the appropriate service. (Assuming an enum `MessageType`):

```java
public class MessageServiceFactory {
    public MessageService getService(Message m, MessageType type){
        switch(type) {
            case SMS:
                return new SmsService(m);
            case EMAIL:
                return new EmailService(m);
            default:
                // throw some exception.
        }
    }   
}
```

Then to do the actual transformation:

```java
Message convertMessage(Message m, MessageType type) {
    return new MessageServiceFactory().getService(m, type)
                                      .transform();
}
```

Comment: I have added the implementation I have done so far. Using Factory or Strategy is solving just one part of my problem. The other is to do an effective transformation of Message objects.

Comment: @SanveerSingh what do you exactly mean by an "effective transformation"? In the above  way, the transformation logic is available in the EmailService/SmsService which would take a message and transform it to the appropriate form.

Comment: Something like a Decorator Pattern. But instead of decorating the object, I want to perform transformation.

Comment: Note that `MessageServiceFactory` is a parameterized [Static Factory Method](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info), which is unrelated to the GoF Factory patterns.

Comment: Oh, I was not criticizing the implementation, only clarifying terminology: there is no "Factory Pattern"; Factory is a category of many patterns. Without the `static` modifier, it now implements what is commonly called the Simple Factory pattern (from Head First design).